# How to add custom info window on iOS with clusters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, infowindow, markerclusterer

I have searched on this for several days now. Found out that this was not possible before, but they have implemented it recently.

[Issue link](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/63)
But there is no proper documentation on how to implement it. I tried setting the title value for markers through the following method.

```
- (void)renderer:(id<GMUClusterRenderer>)renderer willRenderMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
if ([marker.userData isKindOfClass:[ClusterMakerItem class]]) {
    ClusterMakerItem *item = (ClusterMakerItem *)marker.userData;

    if([item.type isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapIconsEvent"];
    }else if([item.type isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mapIconsPromo"];
    }else{
        marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapIconsUpdate"];
    }
    marker.title = item.name;
    // Center the marker at the center of the image.
    marker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
} else if ([marker.userData conformsToProtocol:@protocol(GMUCluster)]) {
    marker.title = @"This is a cluter";
}
```

}

The method gets called but the info window does not show up for any of the map Markers/Clusters. Has anyone managed to actually get it to work? Or am I trying to do something that is not possible at the moment? Any help would be much appreciated.  I have tried the following as well. Still no luck.

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{
     NSLog(@"markerInfoWindow");
     ClusterMakerItem *item = (ClusterMakerItem *)marker.userData;
     NSArray * arr =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomMapWindow" owner:self options:nil];
     CustomMapWindow *customView = [arr firstObject];
     customView.titleLbl.text = item.name;

     return customView;
 }
```

Above method will not get fired.

Comment: Did you resolve this somehow?

Comment: I'm curious also. Apple is really pushing us to use Swift as programming language...